# Use new Android lollipop Camera2 API

Tags: android, android-camera

I've an app that implement a custom camera only for take picture, coded and tested on jelly bean devices. After update of my device to lollipop, my app keep crash, so i need to write again my app, by using new API. There's some good tutorial for do it? because on android developer site there's only old tutorial

Comment: Share what have you tried so far? Only description would not help you get good answers. And You may get close votes on this question as you have asked for the tutorials/offline resources.

Comment: Posting as a comment as user "AppGeek" has posted but doesn't have enough reputation. http://www.kaustubhraghavan.com/camera2.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is very nice sample code from Google explaining beautifully about Camera2 APIs. I used this sample code to study Camera2 APIs: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic

Just for my curiosity I want to know what type of error you are getting when you run your app on Lollipop device. As far as I know Android Lollipop camera2 APIs provide backward compatibility also.